# How to handle 2 iframes with same class name

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Header section editor

```
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="display: inline-block; min-height: 160px;;">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body class="wysihtml5-editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" style="overflow: hidden; min-height: 0px; background-color:;: rgb(255, 255, 255">
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
<div class="p-help-block"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Footer section editor

```
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="display: inline-block; min-height: 160px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <body class="wysihtml5-editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" style="overflow: hidden; min-height: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255">
  </html>
  </iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="p-help-block"></div>
  </div>
```

i can able to enter the text in the header section editor by below code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("div_1_1_3_1_3_1_2_1_1_1_1")) ; 
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("wysihtml5-sandbox"))); 
System.out.println("inside the header frame");
driver.findElement(By.className("wysihtml5-editor")).sendKeys("header section quote approval details");
```

Thread.sleep(10000);
   System.out.println("entered text inside header frame");

but webdriver control is not navigating to the footer section editor to enter the text be below code i tried

```
driver.findElement(By.id("div_1_1_3_1_2_1_1_1_1_1_4-in")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("inside the footer frame");
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.className("wysihtml5-editor")).sendKeys("footer section quote approval details");
System.out.println("entered text inside footer frame");
```

Note : please let me know the solution for this as i am facing same issue in many phases in my application which i am doing automation using selenium webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try with iframe index like following:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0); //To switch to first iframe
//Few actions
driver.switchTo().frame(1); //To switch to second iframe
```

Answer (score 4):

Use an [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression to locate the `<iframe>`.

For the first one:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='wysihtml5-sandbox'][1]"));
```

For the second one:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='wysihtml5-sandbox'][2]"));
```

Alternatively, ask the developers to add an `id` to the different iframes, so you can distinguish them. That would be a more elegant solution than the XPath solution, above, because it will mean your tests continue to work even if more iframes are added to the document.

Comment: I upvoted this for the fact that working with the developers to get Ids is really your best bet if at all possible.